# Using ParseQueryString in Winform

Tags: vb.net, winforms, urldecode

My program is writing URL-encoded strings into a text file like this one.

```
topic1=1&topic2=2&topic3=3&
```

However, I'm trying to reverse the process by opening the same file and breaking that file up in a manner that I can retrieve into name/value-like pairs.

```
' Final Challenge Category
    Dim sr As StreamReader = New StreamReader("./Game" + nudGameNo.Value.ToString() + "/Final/category.txt")
    strLine = WebUtility.UrlDecode(sr.ReadLine)
```

The closest function that I can find to help is [`HttpUtility.ParseQueryString`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.web.httputility.parsequerystring?view=netframework-4.7.2) but I can't seem to run it in a `WinForms` application. (Even if I use `Imports System.Web`)

I've also tried to do a `.Split` with `&` being the separator, however problems start up if a particular value contains an `&` of it's own.

Is it possible to break this form of string up?

Comment: Did you add a reference to the `System.Web.dll` assembly (project reference)?

Comment: Since your program is writing the file, can you use a different deliminator that does not appear anywhere else in the file?

Comment: @Mary Unfortunately I cannot, it must be the `&` delimiter. (The output is being used by another program that I do not have the ability to change.)

Comment: @Jimi That resolved the issue for me.